# How to create directory if doesn't exists in sftp

Tags: shell, sftp

I want to create a directory if it doesn't exists after login to sftp server.

test.sh

```
sftp name@example.com << EOF
mkdir test
put test.xml
bye
EOF
```

Now i call test.sh and upload different files each time to test folder. When running this

```
mkdir test
```

First time it works and second time it throws Couldn't create directory: Failure error?

How to create a directory if doesn't exists and if exists don't create directory in sftp.

Comment: Does your account have regular ssh access to that machine to or is it restricted to sftp?

Comment: i have both regular ssh access as well as sftp.

Answer (score 12):

`man 1 sftp` (from `openssh-client` package):

```
-b batchfile

    Batch mode reads a series of commands from an input
    batchfile instead of stdin. Since it lacks user
    interaction it should be used in conjunction with
    non-interactive authentication. A batchfile of ‘-’
    may be used to indicate standard input. sftp will
    abort if any of the following commands fail: get,
    put, reget, reput, rename, ln, rm, mkdir, chdir, ls,
    lchdir, chmod, chown, chgrp, lpwd, df, symlink, and
    lmkdir. Termination on error can be suppressed on a
    command by command basis by prefixing the command
    with a ‘-’ character (for example, -rm /tmp/blah*).
```

So:

```
{
  echo -mkdir dir1
  echo -mkdir dir1/dir2
  echo -mkdir dir1/dir2/dir3
} | sftp -b - $user@$host
```

Comment: Ok, but this is not anwer to the question. The trick with "-" just avoids termination of SFTP batch processing, but does not avoid the error itself.

Comment: **@lef** OMG, I am under the table )) For the purity you may use ancient utility `expect` that allows automation of interaction with interactive program. It's great utility but unnecessary dependency for simple task.

Comment: @gaveonka Irrelevant. The task was to avoid commmands if the directory exists, without error - so there is no spamming failure message in output - and not to continue with them if it exists.

Comment: Use `expect` as I told you. There are a lot of `expect` bindings into Python/Perl but in later case you may use direct libraries for SFTP access.

Comment: You keep me cheerful )) If you or anyone else still have interest on subject welcome to check my release instruction from http://hg.defun.work/gadict/file/tip/Makefile Search for `sftp` keyword and look around.

Answer (score 8):

I understand this thread is old and has been marked as answered but the answer did not work in my case. The second page on google for a search regarding "sftp checking for directory" so here is an update that would have saved me a few hours.

Using an EOT you cannot capture the error code resulting from the directory not being found. The work around I found was to create a file containing instructions for the call and then capture the result of that automated call.

The example below using sshpass but my script also uses this same method authenticating with sshkeys.

Create the file containing the instructions:

```
echo "cd $RemoteDir" > check4directory
cat check4directory; echo "bye" >> check4directory
```

Set permissions:

```
chmod +x check4directory
```

Then make the connection using the batch feature:

```
export SSHPAA=$remote_pass
sshpass -e sftp -v -oBatchMode=no -b check4directory $remote_user@$remote_addy
```

Lastly check for the error code:

```
if [ $? -ge "1" ] ; then
  echo -e "The remote directory was not found or the connection failed."
fi
```

At this point you can exit 1 or initiate some other action. Note that if the SFTP connection fails for another reason like password or the address is incorrect the error will trip the action.

Answer (score 5):

Another variant is to split the SFTP session into two.

First SFTP session simply issues the MKDIR command.

Second SFTP session can then assume existence of the directory and put the files.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the SSH access of your account to first verify if the directory exists at all (using the "test" command). If it returns exit code 0, the dir exists, otherwise it doesn't. You can act on that accordingly.

```
# Both the command and the name of your directory are "test"
# To avoid confusion, I just put the directory in a separate variable
YOURDIR="test"

# Check if the folder exists remotely
ssh name@example.com "test -d $YOURDIR"

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  # Directory does not exist
  sftp name@example.com << EOF
  mkdir test
  put test.xml
  bye
  EOF
else
  # Directory already exists
  sftp name@example.com << EOF
  put test.xml
  bye
  EOF
fi
```

Comment: For pure SFTP solutions (in case you do not have a shell access or the target server is not *nix) see: [How to check if file exists in remote Windows from local Linux script?](http://superuser.com/questions/850158/how-to-check-if-file-exists-in-remote-windows-from-local-linux-script)

Comment: @OldSkool I want a check directory after login into sftp server not in shell script.

Comment: @karan Since you mentioned you also have SSH access this script first checks the directories existence **over SSH**. So it does the check remotely.

Comment: Just worth noting, that ssh check is not an option in case @karan's server was configured with only chrooted SFTP access in its openssl service, a common situation. karan however confirms he has regular ssh access, so it's apparently simplier to use ssh check.

Comment: if you have ssh acces too, its much simpler to create the directory with mkdir -p like this: `ssh name@example.com "mkdir -p $YOURDIR"`, then do the copy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to ignore errors if directory already exists.

```
# Turn OFF error
set +e

# Create remote dirs
sftp -P 22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -oIdentityFile=key.pem -v $user@$host <<EOF
mkdir <remote_path> # create remote directory
bye
EOF

# Turn ON error
set -e

# Do upload to SFTP
sftp -P 22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -oIdentityFile=key.pem -v $user@$host <<EOF
cd <remote_path>  # remote_path
put <local_file_path> # local_path
quit
EOF
```